# XSLT : Gather and merge information from several files

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm trying to gather information from several xml files and merge this info in one unique xml file using xslt

Here's my original XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<objects>
    <object>
        <class>Class1</class>
        <attribute name="name" value="object1"/>
        <attribute name="id" value="1"/>
    </object>
    <object>
        <class>Class1</class>
        <attribute name="name" value="object2"/>
        <attribute name="id" value="2"/>
    </object>
    <object>
        <class>Class2</class>
        <attribute name="name" value="object3"/>
        <attribute name="id" value="3"/>
    </object>
</objects>
```

I've got a second xml file (res.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<resources>
    <lang id="1">localizedObject1</lang>
</resources>
```

I've got a third xml file (res2.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<resources>
    <lang id="1">localizedObjectDesc1</lang>
</resources>
```

This is the result I'd like to get:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<objects>
    <object>
        <class>Class1</class>
        <attribute name="name" value="object1"/>
        <attribute name="id" value="1"/>
        <attribute name="localizedValue" value="localizedObject1"/>
        <attribute name="localizedDescription" value="localizedObjectDesc1"/>
    </object>
    <object>
        <class>Class1</class>
        <attribute name="name" value="object2"/>
        <attribute name="id" value="2"/>
    </object>
    <object>
        <class>Class2</class>
        <attribute name="name" value="object3"/>
        <attribute name="id" value="3"/>
    </object>
</objects>
```

For all objects where class=Class1 and id is in res.xml => add an attribute (localizedValue). If id is in res2.xml => add an attribute localizedDescription
For all other objects => just copy the node

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be easier ways, but this works good in your case:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="xml"/>
<xsl:variable name="idXML" select="document('a2.xml')/resources" />

<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="object">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" /> 
    <xsl:variable name="curValue" select="attribute[@name='id']/@value" />   
    <xsl:if test="class = 'Class1' and $idXML/lang[@id = $curValue]">
      <attribute name="localizedValue" value="{$idXML/lang[@id = $curValue]/text()}"/>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The output is as desired. You can also add further documents as variables at the beginning and access them in the same way(`$idXML/...`).

Comment: Thanks for the answer ! Both answers (yours and Martin's) helped me to solve my problem. But I stayed on yours since I enabled me to have less maintenance when adding new files and behaviors.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can use an XSLT 2.0 processor you can define a key

```
<xsl:key name="ref" match="resources/lang" use="@id"/>
```

and then use it as follows:

```
<xsl:variable name="res-doc" select="document('res.xml')"/>
<xsl:variable name="res-doc2" select="document('res2.xml')"/>


<xsl:template match="object[class = 'Class1']/attribute[name = 'id']">
  <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="key('ref', value, $res-doc)"/>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="key('ref', value, $res-doc2)" mode="desc"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="resources/lang">
  <attribute name="localizedValue" value="{.}"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="resources/lang" mode="desc">
  <attribute name="localizedDescription" value="{.}"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Of course make sure you include the identity transformation template to copy the rest unchanged:

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Hi Martin, yes I can use XSLT 2.0. So this seems to be quite an elegant solution. Thanks. However, using the xsl:key leads me to another question : how do I merge with a third file (that has the same structure than the second) ? I edited the original question.

Comment: @FVi, adding the other document is easy, only as the element structure is the same it seems but you want a slightly different output it is necessary to use a mode. See the edit.